# How to implement multi language support in android

Tags: android

I display set of string from rss feed in textview formate. in case if feed displays different language i cant get the exact language. is it possible to display the multi language in textview. pls guide me.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please, ask your question more exactly.

If you mean: can I use text in different language in one textview in same time, then yes you can because Android use utf-8